# Ajax call not able to return data before form submit

Tags: php, jquery

Now this is my file getcountshare.php which returns count value which is 5 as below:

```
/*    getcountshare.php */

include "config.php";

$query = "select count(sharecount_id) from brand_testimonial_sharecount where sharecount_fbid='".$fbid."'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$sharecount = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $sharecount;

return $sharecount; //returns sharecount=5

//end

/* File registeration.php where ajax is call */

<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var countshare=0; //global variable


function validateform()
{ 

    getsharecount();

    if(countshare==5) //countshare=5 submit form
    {
         $('#profileForm').submit();
    }

    return false;   
}

function getsharecount()
{

  var url = "https://solutions.techshastra.com/fbapps/newapptest/getcountshare.php?meid=10001020002";

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: url,   
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            countshare=data; //retrieves countshare=5
        }

    });  // end of ajax

}

</script>

<form id="profileForm" name="profileForm" action="thankyou.php"  method="POST" onsubmit="javascript:return validateform();" >


</form>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is i am unable to get countshare value as 5.The ajax call is not returning any value.

Comment: Please post your javascript and AJAX call, the error could be as easily be there.

Comment: Just use the base url instaed of full url like  var url = "/techshastra.com/fbapps/newapptest/getcountshare.php?meid=10001020002";

Comment: without the ajax call, is it echoing 5?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy.  What you need is:

```
$query = "select count(sharecount_id) AS share from brand_testimonial_sharecount where   sharecount_fbid='".$fbid."'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$sharecount = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $sharecount['share'];
```

If you use an alert to display the HTTPResponseText from your PHP it will show something like ARRAY().

Comment: No i have done this and let me explain you that i am getting that count when i hit that URL, but its the error which is seen in firebug that is 200 OK and it comes in red.